# Saving values from a session JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a website and what I need to do is: whenever a user browses over a URL that contains a particular string (let's say "-post-update") I want to capture some credentials from that page. Now when the user closes the browser and comes back, I want to get the saved credentials back. How can I do it in JavaScript?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're wanting to sent a list of all page headers with every request to your server, you'll probably be better off using [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to achieve this objective. Look at that link for a reference, but the basic idea is as follows:

```js
const headings = localStorage.getItem('pageHeadings').split(',')
console.log(headings)
headings.append(window.title)
localStorage.setItem('pageHeadings', headings.join(','))
```